# Why am I getting params value as an hash for simple_form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My simple_form code

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :post,:as => :text %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Where `post` is a `Post.new` and `:post` is a column of `Post`.

Since my create  method was not saving value as expected , I just printed the value of `:post` params in `create.html.erb` and the output was `{"post"=>"My sample post"}`.

**create.html.erb**

```
@post = params[:post]
```

Why does `params[:post]` give `{"post"=>"My sample post"}`  instead of `My sample post`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting wrong output. The output is right.

Because in rails params structure is like below:

```
params[:model_name][:attribute_name]
```

So if you want to print your expected result then try use `params[:post][:post]` instead of `params[:post]`

Answer (score 1):

You have an object called post which you are passing to simple_form_for, so it's wrapping the contents of that form in a hash called post. This allows rails to distinguish between attributes which are the contents of that form and those which are not.

If you added, for instance, a description field, `params[:post]` would look like this.

```
{:post => 'my title', :description => 'aaaa'}
```

I think this may just be a little confusing because you've called both the model and the attribute 'post'. Perhaps if you renamed the column to 'contents' this would be clearer.